# Entity framework key not defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a class like this

```
     public class Phone : ItemBase
    {
        public virtual string Model { get; set; }

        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public virtual string ImagePath { get; set; }

        public virtual string Network { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Dimensions")]
        public virtual string BodyDimension { get; set; }
}
```

and a base class like this

```
 public class ItemBase
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public virtual long ItemID;

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

the key is defined in the base class, but EF says

> Phone :: The entity type 'Phone' has no key defined. Define the key
>   for entity type.

Should I move the key field to Phone class ?
What would be the best solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to mark virtual on `ItemId` field
2. make `ItemId` property instead of fields.

something like this:

```
    public class ItemBase
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Key]
        public long ItemID {get; set;}

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public virtual DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
```